# "<<<DATA" - what does this mean?

Tags: php, syntax

I have got this code sample.

```
$data = <<<DATA
MIN={$min}
INVOICE={$invoice}
AMOUNT={$sum}
EXP_TIME={$exp_date}
DESCR={$descr}
DATA;
```

What does this mean? Some string concatenation? I don't know the name of this syntax `("<<<DATA")` construction, to check google what this mean...

Comment: its heredoc syntax http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

Comment: great, 10x for the solution